# Why is $merge not working in aggregate in mongoshell

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

When I run the following code from my mongo shell, I get an errormsg as
 "'on' field '_id' cannot be missing, null, undefined or an array",". What's wrong here

```
db.c1.insertMany([
   { item: "journal", qty: 25, tags: ["blank", "red"], size: { h: 14, w: 21, uom: "cm" } },
   { item: "mat", qty: 85, tags: ["gray"], size: { h: 27.9, w: 35.5, uom: "cm" } },
   { item: "mousepad", qty: 25, tags: ["gel", "blue"], size: { h: 19, w: 22.85, uom: "cm" } }
])

db.c2.insertMany([
   { item: "journal1", qty: 251, tags: ["blank1", "red1"], size: { h: 14, w: 21, uom: "cm" } },
   { item: "mat1", qty: 851, tags: ["gray1"], size: { h: 27.9, w: 35.5, uom: "cm" } },
   { item: "mousepad1", qty: 251, tags: ["gel1", "blue1"], size: { h: 19, w: 22.85, uom: "cm" } }

])

var a = ["c1", "c2"];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

    db[a[i]].aggregate([ 
    {"$addFields":{"arrayofkeyvalue":{"$objectToArray":"$$ROOT"}}}, 
    {"$unwind":"$arrayofkeyvalue"}, 
    {"$group":{"_id":null,"allkeys":{"$addToSet":"$arrayofkeyvalue.k"},item: {$addToSet: "$item"},qty: {$addToSet: "$qty"},tags: {$addToSet: "$item"}}},
    {"$addFields":{db: a[i]}},
    {"$merge": { into: "myOutput", on: "_id" }},
    ])
}
```

Error Log from my mongoshell

```
2019-08-20T13:39:26.327-0500 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: Error: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "$merge write error: 'on' field '_id' cannot be missing, null, undefined or an array",
        "code" : 51132,
        "codeName" : "Location51132"
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:18:14
_assertCommandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:583:17
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:673:16
DB.prototype._runAggregate@src/mongo/shell/db.js:266:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1012:12
```

Comment: Since this question is edited, to keep a track of it, Original issue is :  "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$merge'".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$merge` is only available starting mongo version 4.2,Please check if you've updated to v4.2 as it's very latest as of Aug-20/2019, If you're using `$merge` on v4.0 to merge your aggregation results to some other collection then you need to find other ways as it's not available in version below 4.2, if that's a new collection then you can use `$out` for one time purpose.

Ref : [$merge mongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/index.html#examples)

Comment: Thanks but even when I used the 4.2 version, it throws an error, I have edited the posted. Kindly help

Comment: @VishnuKumar : Seems like they made v4.2 official in last 2days or maybe today, surprising their docs says 4.2 is current as of today but no where in wiki though in mongo portals - seems it has to be updated wide !! I've explored much on 4.2 ($merge) but I can take a look.. So did you check your mongo version is 4.2 ?

Comment: @VishnuKumar : I can see after your upgrade it seems to be a new issue, If you're still seeing issues I can look into it, Is that the same issue or anything new as of now?